# python pandas 'AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values' decimal to hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a df that looks like

```
hour
1.0
2.0
3.0
6.0 
Nan
```

I want to convert this into a time format so like below

```
hour
1:00
2:00
3:00
6:00
```

However I cannot get the formatting correct. I have tried to coerce the format like below. I would also like the logic to leave the Nan values.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], format='%H', coerce=True)
```

But this only returns NaT values.

Comment: The pandas datetime format is for storing a complete date. If you just want the value 1 to be formatted as '1:00' then it's a matter of formatting strings. If this isn't the case, please elaborate on what outcome you're hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], unit='h')
```

Change the `format` to `unit`. If you are using numeric data (like you are), then you **cannot** use `format`. `format` works only on strings.

`%H`, for example is string interpolation, and since your data is numeric (float), string interpolation will fail.

---

Note that the printed output will not resemble the output in the question. Because, pandas will convert it to datetime type. It will look like `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'` when printed. If you want the desired format, you can run either:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], unit='h').apply(lambda h: '{}:00'.format(h.hour))
```

Or:

```
df['hour'].apply(lambda h: '{}:00'.format(h))
```